# Dont reset fields when message box show up

Tags: python, wxpython

Hi all i am learning python language, and for gui i use wxpython. I have 2 spin ctrl, 1 text ctrl, 1 password ctrl in my GUI. whenever user enter wrong password it will pop-up message that "password is wrong". Then user again should enter password, but what is happening is password field get reset with " 2 spin ctrl, and 1 text ctrl" , i want to keep the value of spinctrl and textctrl when  user enters wrong  password & Message-box will show- up. how to achieve this? Please suggest me.

```
  class child(wx.Frame):    
  self.sc1 = wx.SpinCtrl(self,-1, pos=(-1, -1))
  self.paswd = wxTextCtrl(self, -1, (-1, -1),(30,20))
  def main(self, event):
  lan1 = self.sc1.GetValue()
  password = self.paswd.GetValue()
  if lan1 > 16 :
     wx.MessageBox("zzzzzzzzzzzz","warning")
     if password = license(hard coded):
        """show message box 
        and install"""
     else:
        """re enter password"""
        Child().Show()
   //when child window again pop up spin ctrl also set to 0, i want to keep spin ctrl value when user enter wrong password.
```

Comment: @alecxe i did only that much whatever i have mentioned in description but afterwards started searching but didn't get solution , so i asked for suggestion or links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post what you already have so we can see where you went wrong. It would also be good to know which version of wxPython and Python you're using as well as which OS. Regardless, here is one way to do it:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class LoginPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        userSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        pwdSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        userLbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Username:")
        userSizer.Add(userLbl, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.userTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        userSizer.Add(self.userTxt, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)

        pwdLbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Password:")
        pwdSizer.Add(pwdLbl, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.pwdTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
        pwdSizer.Add(self.pwdTxt, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)

        loginBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Login") 
        loginBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onLogin)

        self.mainSizer.Add(userSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.mainSizer.Add(pwdSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.mainSizer.Add(loginBtn, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onLogin(self, event):
        """
        Login or show msg box if password wrong
        """
        username = self.userTxt.GetValue()
        pwd = self.pwdTxt.GetValue()

        if pwd == "password":
            print "logging in"
        else:
            msg = "Wrong password or username!"
            wx.MessageBox(msg, "Error", wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)


########################################################################
class LoginFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Login")
        panel = LoginPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = LoginFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: i have edited my question please check and tell me whats wrong in program logic